# Looping through every record from database

Tags: php, mysql

I've searched on the internet for this, and questions here on SO but mostly are using something else than PHP. So i will ask my own question.

What i need to do is make a button that will print out (read literally print, as in downloading a word document with all details on it) every record from the database.

The ID is named 'abstract_id'.

What i'm going to show you next is the print button from all pages, what i mean by this is if you click on said button it will print everything from that specific page:

```
$abstract_id = addslashes($_POST['abstract_id']);  

 //Here i connect to the database//

$query = "SELECT * FROM abstracts WHERE abstract_id = '$abstract_id'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    $i = 0;
    $title = mysql_result($result,$i,"title");
    $author[1] = mysql_result($result,$i,"author1");
    $organization[1] = mysql_result($result,$i,"organization1");
    $author[2] = mysql_result($result,$i,"author2");
    $organization[2] = mysql_result($result,$i,"organization2");
    $author[3] = mysql_result($result,$i,"author3");
    $organization[3] = mysql_result($result,$i,"organization3");
    $author[4] = mysql_result($result,$i,"author4");
    $organization[4] = mysql_result($result,$i,"organization4");
    $author[5] = mysql_result($result,$i,"author5");
    $organization[5] = mysql_result($result,$i,"organization5");
    $author[6] = mysql_result($result,$i,"author6");
    $organization[6] = mysql_result($result,$i,"organization6");
    $format = mysql_result($result,$i,"format");
    $language = mysql_result($result,$i,"language");
    $presenter = mysql_result($result,$i,"presenter");
    $background = mysql_result($result,$i,"background");
    $purpose = mysql_result($result,$i,"purpose");
    $methods = mysql_result($result,$i,"methods");
    $findings = mysql_result($result,$i,"findings");
    $conclusion = mysql_result($result,$i,"conclusion");
    $word_count = mysql_result($result,$i,"word_count");
    $name = mysql_result($result,$i,"name");
    $email1 = mysql_result($result,$i,"email1");
    $email2 = mysql_result($result,$i,"email2");
    $phone1 = mysql_result($result,$i,"phone1");
    $phone2 = mysql_result($result,$i,"phone2");
    $fax = mysql_result($result,$i,"fax");
    $address = mysql_result($result,$i,"address");
    $country = mysql_result($result,$i,"country");
    $topic = mysql_result($result,$i,"topic");
    $master_status = mysql_result($result, $i, "master_status");
    $last_edit = mysql_result($result,$i,"last_edit");


    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=abstract_" . $abstract_id . ".doc");

    echo "<html>";
    echo "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=Windows-1252\">";
    echo "<body>";
    echo "<p><b>PCNE Abstract</b> $abstract_id</p>";
    echo "<h1>$title</h1>";

    echo "<b>";
    for ($i = 1; $i<= 6; $i++) {
        echo ((!empty($author[$i-1]) && !empty($author[$i])) ? ", " : "") ;
        echo ((!empty($author[$i])) ? $author[$i] . "<sup>" . $i . "</sup>" : "") ;
    }
    echo ".</b>";

    echo "<br>";

    for ($i = 1; $i<= 6; $i++) {
        if (!empty($author[$i])) {
            echo (!empty($organization[$i]) && !empty($organization[$i-1])) ? ". " : "";
            echo ((!empty($organization[$i])) ? "<sup>" . $i . "</sup>"  . $organization[$i]: "") ;
        }
    }
    echo (!empty($email1)) ? " (" . $email1 . ")" : "";

    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";

    echo "<b>Background</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;";   
    echo "$background<br>"; 

    echo "<b>Purpose</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;";      
    echo "$purpose<br>";    

    echo "<b>Method</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;";       
    echo "$methods<br>";    

    echo "<b>Findings</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;";     
    echo "$findings<br>";   


    echo "<b>Conclusion</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;";       
    echo "$conclusion<br>"; 


    echo "</body>";
    echo "</html>";
```

Now, this works fine, but i need a same working button which does almost the same, but instead of printing out 1 record it should print all. So all i basically need is a foreach or while loop that goes through every abstract_id.

It's been ages since i last programmed php, so i appreciate any help!

If you need any clarification, feel free to ask.

Comment: Right now, you have a single abstract_id on the page. Where are the rest of the abstract_id's coming from - how will they get to the page. Are they stored somewhere, or do they depend on a user selecting or inputting multiple abstract_id's?

Comment: @larsAnders The code i wrote above is on each specific page which is tied to a unique abstract_id in the database. But i need a button (a layer above each individually page) That prints out ALL pages. (sorry it's really hard to explain.

Comment: Are there records in this database that have no abstract_id, or will every single record have one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you don't need your 30 lines of mysql_result, just use mysql_fetch_assoc to get all values in associative array.
Then you just have to do a while ( $line = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) ), see above :

```
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=abstract_all.doc");

echo "<html>";
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=Windows-1252\">";
echo "<body>";

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM abstracts WHERE 1") or die(mysql_error()) ;
while ( $line = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) )
{
    echo "<p><b>PCNE Abstract</b>".$line['abstract_id']."</p>";
    echo "<h1>".$line['title']."</h1>";

    $authors = Array() ;
    for ($i = 1 ; $i <= 6 ; $i++ )
        if ( isset($line['author'.$i]) && $line['author'.$i] != '' ) $authors[] = $line['author'.$i].' <sup>'.$i.'</sup>' ;
    echo '<b>'.implode(', ',$authors).'</b>' ;

    $organizations = Array() ;
    for ($i = 1; $i<= 6; $i++)
    {
        if ( ! isset($line['author'.$i]) || $line['author'.$i] == '' ) continue ; // Check if there is an author, if no go to next loop
        if ( isset($line['organization'.$i]) && $line['organization'.$i] != '' ) $organizations[] = ' <sup>'.$i.'</sup> '.$line['organization'.$i] ;
    }
    echo '<b>'.implode(', ',$organizations).'</b>' ;

    echo "<b>Background</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;";   
    echo $line['background']."<br>"; 

    echo "<b>Purpose</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;";      
    echo $line['purpose']."<br>";    

        // ...
}

echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";
```

Comment: Sorry, i'm a bit confused. Do i just place the code you provided directly beneath the $result = mysql_query($query); ? And just remove all the mysql_results?

Comment: No you can replace your whole code with this (take care of the // ..., i didn't edit all)

First it push the headers, after you've got a while wich parse all your lines on your SQL table (is that reall what you want ?), and after the loop you just close body and html. This is supposed to print all your abstracts on the same word doc.

Comment: It will download an empty file. Wait let me put together some images to make it easier to explain.

Comment: You're saying my code will download an empty page or this is what you're expecting ?

Comment: It's downloading and empty word document. I removed everything except the database connection. And added of course the code from you

Comment: Can you comment the 2 headers on first lines and add this :
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1); Just to see where the error is, i havn't tested the code

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/hYGjt0X.png this is btw what im trying to accomplish. The black print button needs to print all records. Meanwhile i will do what you told me.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you so much! the error was that it didn't know what 'mysq_fetch_assoc' was... all that needed was an 'l' mysql*. It works now. except that it doesnt show me all info. But i will add those myself right now.

Comment: wow im't not sure at all i understand your question... You have an HTML list in a web browser. Each entry have a green button, and when you click on it, it open another page already in web browser wich display one whole abstract page corresponding to variable i ?

Comment: Ok let me explain it properly this time. I have a webpage, with all ID's beneath eachother. With just the title and a button that has VIEW  on it. If a user clicks on view. It will open a new page according to the ID that he clicked view on. There it will show all the details that are tied with the ID in the database. Also there is a print button on that same page that can print all details on that very page.

Now what I need to do, is make a same working print button on the main page, that will print ALL articles with all data with them.

Comment: It's so hard to explain. But you seem to have fixed my issue without even knowing what exactly i wanted. btw, what did you mean when you said "is that reall what you want?" before?

Comment: I hope i can ask you a quick question, which (should be) is my last one. Everything works great, thanks!, but i miss one thing. The for loop with authors works also great but there is supposed to be an other same loop with organizations. I've played around with it but i can't seem to get it work. In my question you will see the for loop for authors and directly beneath it the for loop for organization. I hope you still have time to fix this tiny issue for me!

Comment: And i've fixed this one as well. I guess i won't be needing any help anymore. Thanks again for your effort!